# How to know the individual cost for each of the instances in aws?

Tags: cloud, aws

I need to know what the individual cost for each is of my 4 EC2 instances this month. But in the billing, I can only see the combined cost for all the instances in a region. Is there a way to know what is the individual cost?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you uniquely tag the instances, you can't derive the cost of individual instances (though you can naively do a divide by 4 - especially if they are all of the same instance type/family and have similar usage patterns)